# Adding Acrobat JavaScript code to pdf export

Tags: javascript, pdf, openoffice.org, acrobat, uno

I need to add startup Acrobat JavaScript code to pdf file while exporting to pdf (from ods or odt) by OpenOffice uno API (in C#). The code should by called when PDF is being opened or just has been opened.

I already know other solutions to the problem, but what I would like to solve is that certain approach(Acrobat JavaScript code + OpenOffice + UNO + PDF Export).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the javascript code gets executed as soon as the PDF file is opened. There is not document open event.